# Cheat Sheet or Flowchart for Computer Vision

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I was curious if anyone knew of something like [this flowchart](http://peekaboo-vision.blogspot.com/2013/01/machine-learning-cheat-sheet-for-scikit.html) but for Computer Vision tasks? Specifically for OpenCV would be most ideal.

Or any references with best practices, and common patterns for Computer Vision problems?

Comment: a cheat sheet for which part of computer vision? or which concrete task?

Answer (score 4):

That's a monumental task. The best I could find is from [this article](http://www.embedded-vision.com/technology/computer-vision-algorithms) and it's a little bit old:

[image]

Maybe it's a good time to commit to [FlexCV](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/726845063/flexcv-flexible-computer-vision-video-software) on Kickstarter.com, a GUI for OpenCV that allows you to create complex algorithms in a matter of minutes by connecting graphical elements together. It's an alternative for [Adaptive Vision](https://adaptive-vision.com/en/), but purely based on OpenCV features.